# Java file canonicalPath with tailing '.. ' leads to inconsistent behavior

Tags: java, nio, canonical-link

I'm currently investigating in some pathTraversal related security mechanisms and came across a weird behavior of java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(). I thought CanonicalPath will always represent the true unique path of the abstract underlying File. However if the file name consists a of two dots followed by a space the CanonicalPath does not seem to represent the correct path anymore.

Here is the example:

```
File root = new File("c:/git/");
String relative = ".. /.. \\";
File concatFile = new File (root.getCanonicalPath(), relative);

System.out.println("ConcatFileAbsolute: '" + concatFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
System.out.println("ConcatFileCanonical: '" + concatFile.getCanonicalPath() + "'");

File canonFile = new File(concatFile.getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println("\ncanonFileCanonical: '" + canonFile.getCanonicalPath() + "'");
System.out.println("canonFileAbsolute: '" + canonFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
System.out.println("canonFileName: '" + canonFile.getName() + "'\n");

for (File file : canonFile.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println("canon: '" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "' - absolute: '" + file.getAbsolutePath()+ "'");
}
```

Console Output:

```
ConcatFileAbsolute: 'C:\git\.. \.. '
ConcatFileCanonical: 'C:\git\.. \'

canonFileCanonical: 'C:\git\'
canonFileAbsolute: 'C:\git\.. '
canonFileName: '.. '

canon: 'C:\git\.. \$Recycle.Bin' - absolute: 'C:\git\.. \$Recycle.Bin'
canon: 'C:\git\.. \.m2' - absolute: 'C:\git\.. \.m2'
canon: 'C:\git\.. \boot' - absolute: 'C:\git\.. \boot'
...other content of C:/
```

As you can see although the canonicalPath of canonFile clearly indicates it's location in C:\git\, but .listFiles lists all files in C:.

This only happens if I use the new File(String, String) constructor. If I change the third line to File concatFile = new File (root.getCanonicalPath() + relative); then the output is as expected:

```
ConcatFileAbsolute: 'C:\git.. \.. '
ConcatFileCanonical: 'C:\git\' 
- The following output then lists files under C:\git\
```

I don't know if this behavior is similar on unix-like systems.

Can somebody clarify this behavior? Is this intended?

Thanks upfront!

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, edit the question, code in comments is largely unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congrats! You found a possible bug (or feature?) of WinAPI.

More specifically, your question can be reduced to one line of code:

Why does `new File("c:\\temp\\.. ").getCanonicalPath()` returns `c:\temp\` instead of `c:\`?

Short answer: because of tailing space after `..` (yep, you've mentioned above it).

Long answer: if we will look inside Java implementation of underlying class, we will found that for Windows it is `WinNTFileSystem` class, where **native** method `canonicalize0("c:\\temp\\.. ")` returns this broken value. Why? 
To test it I've written simple VBS code to test Win API:

```
Dim folderName
folderName = "c:\temp\.. "

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim fullpath
fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(folderName)

WScript.Echo "fullpath:    " & fullpath
```

It gives exactly same result:

```
fullpath:    C:\temp
```

Comment: Is there any kind of error reporting on that call? `.. ` looks like a filename, the API might be just deciding to toss it as an invalid one. Either way not returning `c:\` doesn't seem completely unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much. This explains it at least to OS level! I looked up the implementation of java.io.File (construtor as well as getCanonicalPath) and you are right. The fs-specific implementation of canonicalize and resolve seem to be the problem.